# Wildcard SSL Certifcate Installation

Tags: installation, ssl-certificate

A customer has purchased a wild-card certificate SSL for there domain, which I have managed to install on WHM as under nobody.  However if you navigate to the site with HTTPS, it shows the default website page instead of the main site.

Examples:

- http://mistral-online.com/ (Works with HTTP)
- https://mistral-online.com/ (HTTPS redirects)
- https://mistral-online.com/~mistral/ (Works with HTTPS)

We previously installed a normal SSL certificate which worked, so are there any additional steps I need to get the wild-card SSL certificate to work?

Comment: This behavior is unrelated to the SSL wildcard certificate. A SSL certificate will not change cause a redirect on your HTTPS server. Please check for other changes which occurred at the same time. If you haven't restarted the server in a while, it's possible that this restart picked up any changes made within the last few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain IP address was shared with the WHM, so it needed its own dedicated IP address before the wild card certificate would work.

Reference: http://www.thecpaneladmin.com/installing-wildcard-ssl-certificate/